# I want to implement loading content page once masterpage is loaded

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, page-loading-message

I want to load the content page once the master page content is loaded. I have tried something like this
 default.aspx

```
  <script type="text/javascript">
    function ShowProgress() {
        setTimeout(function () {
            var modal = $('<div />');
            modal.addClass("modal");
            $('body').append(modal);
            var loading = $(".loading");
            loading.show();
            var top = Math.max($(window).height() / 2 - loading[0].offsetHeight / 2, 0);
            var left = Math.max($(window).width() / 2 - loading[0].offsetWidth / 2, 0);
            loading.css({ top: top, left: left });
        }, 200);
    }
    $('form').submit("submit", function () {
        ShowProgress();
    });
 </script>
 <asp:Button ID="btnSubmit" runat="server" Text="Load Customers"
OnClick="btnSubmit_Click"  /<div class="loading" align="center">
Loading. Please wait.<br />
<br />
<img src="image/loading.gif" width="50" alt="" />
  </div>
```

here is the default.aspx.cs code

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!IsPostBack)
    {
        string script = "$(document).ready(function () { $('[id*=btnSubmit]').click(); });";
        ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "load", script, true);
    }
}
protected void btnSubmit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(5000);
    Repeater1.DataSource = GetKioskData(1);
    Repeater1.DataBind();
}
```

Comment: ok, so what happens ? any issue ?

Comment: Bad idea, and unless your data make more than 30 seconds to load, you not get any better speed or better impression of page load. Now if you data takes so long to load, you need to change your design and load them faster.

Comment: data is not loading. I don't know why